# How can I log all requests by an app including post data? (Squid?)

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm testing a flash app and need to log every HTTP post request it makes so I need to be able. My default setting is to use squid. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your server, run:

```
$ tcpdump -w ~/capture.log -s 0 port 80
```

That will capture all traffic on port 80 and log it to `capture.log` in your home directory. After starting this command, perform whatever actions you are testing, and then `Ctrl-C` to stop the capture. When complete, you can use either tcpdump or preferrably the GUI program Wireshark to inspect and analyze the capture.

Answer (score 2):

You are testing your app. So, you don't need to keep the logs for a long time.

1- You can use tcpump/wireshark to sniff HTTP traffic. You will have access to all traffic.

2- You can install an add-on for your browser (like firefox) to show you the posted data.

Comment: I just want to log the HTTP requests though.

Comment: Stewart: Khaled is nudging you to right direction. The thing is that POST requests do not usually get logged. Ok, they _are_ logged, it's only that their parameters are missing from the logs, since the parameters are not visible in the URI. :-) So your possibilities are 1) modify the application to log all the POST parameters or 2) Use tcpdump/wireshark or a web browser add-on.